# Convert a string to int array

Tags: android

I need to convert a string stored like,

```
textView.setText(myVar);
```

Here
    myVar = "23,45,64,78";

I would like it to convert into array like below,

```
int[] xAxis = new int[]{23,45,64,78};
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String arr = "[23,45,64,78]";
String[] items = arr.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(",");

int[] results = new int[items.length];

for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    try {
        results[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
}
```

Comment: Too fast for me but edit that response to remove the bracket at least.

Comment: Sorry, new here. I am getting values from textview like this 12 34 56 and how can i add quotes and brackets like this String arr = "[23,45,64,78]"; Thanks